# MySQL to offline database android

Tags: android, mysql

I have a lot of data in server mysql database and want  to use data in android app in offline model of the application. What kind of architecture/design change can be used for offline model?

Comment: maybe sync mysql to SQLite ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQLite Database;

What you can do is make an async task and call it in some duration depending upon your requirements to refresh your SQLite data with MYSQL database using Rest Services

```
`Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, Asynctasktomysql.class);
        pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, ishintent, 0);
        alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.cancel(pintent);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                50000, pintent);`
```

I set a duration of 50 sec in code. You can change it by Your self.

You can call your server for json Object and then parse it Like this :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .disableHtmlEscaping()
                        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class,
                                new JsonDateDeserializer()).create();
                Table1 table1vo = gson.fromJson(jsonObj, Table1.class);
```

After that put all your data in ContentValues and insert into data base

```
final ContentValues InfoCV = CVTransformers
                    .transformContactInfo(table1vo);
            contactInfoCV.put("SEQ", table1vo.getSEQ());
            dbHelper.insert("TABLE1_NAME", null, InfoCV);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a rest api for accessing the MySQL server data (or its parts) and then sync and store with SQLITE on Android.